# Validate a form field in django with a default value

Tags: python, html, django

I'm here working with django and I'm having some problems to validate my login form. I want the text areas to appear with a default value, only for esthetic, and then I want to write the real username. The problem is that, I don't want the default value to be admitted, because it is not a correct username. Same with the password.

I post here my code:

forms.py

```
class AutenticacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username','password']
    widgets={'password': forms.PasswordInput(),}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AutenticacionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].help_text = None
    self.fields['username'].label = ""
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'required':'true','data-html':'true', 'value':'USUARIO', 'onfocus':'this.value="";', 'onblur':'if(this.value == ""){this.value = "USUARIO";}'})
    self.fields['password'].label = ""
    self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({'required':'true','data-html':'true', 'value':'PASSWORD', 'onfocus':'this.value="";', 'onblur':'if(this.value == ""){this.value = "PASSWORD";}'})
```

That's the way my form looks. USUARIO is just a default value, so I don't want the login to admit that value as correct.

[image]

Comment: Read about [placeholders](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) this is what you are looking for

Comment: as another possible (less good) solution, Django forms (and individual fields) have a `has_changed` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#checking-which-form-data-has-changed